# What countries and territories is Google App Engine currently blocked in?

Tags: google-app-engine

I run a website that allows you to hire a journalist anywhere in the world, and we have correspondents in 150 countries. It's hosted on App Engine, and occasionally we get a journalists emailing us to say that our site is not available from where they are. The specific error is:

> Your client does not have permission to get URL xxx from this server.
>   (Client IP address: x.x.x.x)
>
> We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country. That’s
>   all we know.

The locations we have identified so far are: Cuba and Crimea.

I can't find a complete list anywhere, but I really need one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not an official list. I would recommend using [this list](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en) until one specifically for App Engine is created.

> Google restricts access to some of its business services in certain countries or regions, such as Crimea, Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria.

Comment: We run a CDN using GCP (well, we used to :/) and asked Google to update their docs about this, and they said no, but did confirm that list is the best public list they have now of where embargoes are causing them to block access.  We are unaware of any other cloud provider that does this (we use azure, digital ocean, rackspace, host virtual, and AWS and they all work fine in those countries)