# Any Suggestion About Accessing Google Cloud Hosted Website From Iran

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

There is a restriction to access Google Cloud Hosted Website from Iran, i guess. People in Iran can not access our website. Is there anything we can do for users in Iran? Any suggestions?

Comment: Iran, like China, is censoring the web (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Iran). You could try and use a proxy to allow access. Depending on what content you provide you might violate the law in Iran though.

Comment: It'a corporate website. I dont think it violate any law in Iran. How can i use a proxy to allow access? Can you refer a guide for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What countries and territories is Google App Engine currently blocked in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678313/what-countries-and-territories-is-google-app-engine-currently-blocked-in)

Comment: Google for "apache reverse proxy"

Comment: unfortunately reverse proxy doens't work for iran. But thanks for the suggestion. we will create a country spesific domain and hosting for iran.

Comment: We are under sanctions! Google blocked Iranian people from using some of its services. And yes, your easiest option for short term is to host your website inside of Iran, but the maintenance cost can bother. You can use a proxy using a vps and a country specific domain. You can contact me if you need to do so.

Comment: @konqi dude google blocked us. :)

Answer (score 15):

It is not Iran that blocked Google Cloud. It's Google that blocked access of Iranian people to Google Cloud. You may open a ticket with Google Cloud support and ask them this question. They will tell you what I said. If they said it's because [sanction on Iran from U.S. Department of The Treasury](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Pages/iran.aspx). Then you may want to ask them why this is not being applied to other Cloud providers from USA?